# How to find files with same name but different line count in two directories?

Tags: shell-script, diff, wc, file-comparison

I have a directory `sub1` with the following files:

```
$ wc -l *

5 file1.csv
5 file3.csv
1 file4.csv
```

In `sub2`, I have the following:

```
$ wc -l *
5 file1.csv
5 file2.csv
1 file3.csv
5 file4.csv
1 file5.csv
```

In the first directory, I might have files with added lines, which then go to the second dir. In this example, I might need to update `file3` in `sub2`.

How do I get a list of the files with differences?

---

I did some tests with `diff` and `grep`, but it doesn't work because the directories have different files (and hence the lines are different):

```
~/dir1/$ wc -l >> wc.luis

~/dir1/$ wc -l * | awk '{ gsub(/\/home.*dir1\//,""); print $0 }' 
                 | diff --side-by-side wc.luis -
                 | grep \|
```

Ideally, I would get a list like this:

```
5 file3.csv | 1 file3.csv
1 file4.csv | 5 file4.csv
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

Notes:

- I cannot check on the date, because all files were updated, with or without changes.
- Sometimes the newest files *lack* some lines, for which reason I cannot just take the bigger one.

Comment: Isn't this just `diff -r sub1 sub2` or am I missing something?

Comment: That would show all different lines in all different files, and I need only check which files are present in both, but different; and print their line count if possible.

Comment: `diff -r sub1 sub2 | grep ^diff` will just report on the filenames that are present in both but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty shell "one-liner" with example output:

```
$ join -j2 <(cd sub1; wc -l *) <(cd sub2; wc -l *) | awk '$2!=$3'
file3.csv 5 1
file4.csv 1 5
total 11 17
```

The `total` line is an artifact from the output of `wc`. It can be removed with another filter:

```
$ join -j2 <(cd sub1; wc -l *) <(cd sub2; wc -l *) | awk '$2!=$3' | head -n-1
file3.csv 5 1
file4.csv 1 5
```

Explanation:

`join` will join two files based on a common column. In this case we join based on the second column (`-j2`). In the output of `wc` the second column is the filename. This will only print files which are common in both directories.

The `wc` invocations are done in [process substitutions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) with working directory changed to `sub1` or `sub2` so the filenames are printed without directory name. This is so that `join` can find the common files.

The `awk` command compares the value in the second and third column and only prints the line if the values differ. This will filter out files with the same line count.

`head -n-1` will print all lines but not the last line. This will filter out the last `total` line from `wc`.

Comment: Great, thank you! Your approach has also the plus that the line numbers are side-to-side, cool!